# Proving the existence of a triangle's incenter and Gergonne point

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have no idea on how to solve this question so can someone please assist me. My son brought it from school and he is really struggling with the question.

> Consider $\triangle ABC$. Extend the internal angle bisectors at $A$ and $C$ until they meet at a point $I$, and draw
>   perpendiculars from $I$ to the three sides of $\triangle ABC$.
>
> a. Using trigonometry or otherwise, show that these three perpendiculars all have the same length (call it $r$, the *inradius*).
>
> b. Hence show that $\overline{IB}$ is also an angle bisector, and that these all meet at $I$ (the *incentre*).
>
> c. A circle centered at $I$ and with radius $r$ (the *incircle*) is tangent to each side of the triangle. Show that the lines joining the points of contact to the opposite vertices all meet at a single point (called the *Gergonne point*).

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Also, you can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Also, what school does your son go to where they learn about Gergonne points? Wish I had gone there...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the best diagram I found on the internet in image search (next time, try to provide a diagram with the question). It calls the point inside $O$ instead of $I$. Let the point on $AC, CB, BA$ be $X, Y, Z$ respectively. Then all you have to show for the first part is that triangle $AOX$ is congruent to triangle $AOZ$. This is easy because they are both right angled, have equal half angles at $A$ and share a common side $AO$. So $OX = OZ$. You can prove that $OZ = OY$ with a similar argument and so all perpendiculars have the same length. For the next part, you can show that triangle $BOZ$ is congruent to $BOY$. So the two angles at $B$ are equal and hence $OB$ is an angle bisector. A tangent to a circle at point $P$ is perpendicular to $OP$ and passes through $P$. All the sides satisfies this, so they are tangent to the incircle. I am not sure how to do the Gergonne point question.

Comment: Thank you for your help @ Sarkar